# About Mann-Kendall test in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to perform the Mann-Kendall test to attain the spatial change of my yearly growing season composite (named 'growthdata), the'system:index' below in the code is the corresponding year list, i.e., 2000,2001,2002,2003..., this is for differentiating the before and after images. I followed the official guidance from: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/nonparametric-trends this code works but I only get the image with all white color( with all 0 value). Can anyone tell me what's the problem with my code?

```
    enter code here
    ////////////////////////////test mendall code////////////////////////////
var coll= growthdata.select('mean')
var afterFilter = ee.Filter.lessThan({
  leftField: 'system:index',
  rightField: 'system:index'
});
var sign = function(i, j) { // i and j are images
  return ee.Image(j).neq(i) // Zero case
      .multiply(ee.Image(j).subtract(i).clamp(-1, 1)).int();
};


var joined = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveAll('after').apply({
  primary: coll,
  secondary: coll,
  condition: afterFilter
}));
var sign = function(i, j) { // i and j are images
  return ee.Image(j).neq(i) // Zero case
    .multiply(ee.Image(j).subtract(i).clamp(-1, 1)).int()
}

var kendall = ee.ImageCollection(joined.map(function(current) {
  var afterCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(current.get('after'))
  return afterCollection.map(function(image) {
    // The unmask is to prevent accumulation of masked pixels that
    // result from the undefined case of when either current or image
    // is masked.  It won't affect the sum, since it's unmasked to zero.
    return ee.Image(sign(current, image)).unmask(0)
  })
  // Set parallelScale to avoid User memory limit exceeded.
}).flatten()).reduce('sum', 2)

var palette = ['red', 'white', 'green']
// Stretch this as necessary.
Map.addLayer(kendall, {min: -800, max: 200, palette: palette}, 'kendall')
print(joined)
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and unrunnable.  Can you post a link that runs and shows the problem?

Comment: @NoelGorelick Here is my link to follow:  https://code.earthengine.google.com/e7c979158815c29b5bc3ec5116038202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am glad to tell you that I have optimized the code to answer this question, and I would like to share it as a open-source code for all!

I am glad to find that there has appeared a simple code for conducting the Kendall trend, which is *ee.Reducer.kendallsCorrelation()*, together with the simple code *ee.Reducer.sensSlope()* , this problem can be very easily resolved.
You can calculate the MK Kendall Z value as following formula
Z=3×tau×sqrt(n(n-1))/2×sqrt(2n+5)

where:
Z is the Mann-Kendall Z-score

tau is the Kendall's Tau correlation coefficient result of *ee.Reducer.kendallsCorrelation()*

n is the is the number of paired observations.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/397d3adb3922c2353f56fe8fcd3e364f

Here comes my opensource code for everyone who has ever read my question for this 2k times view, I have validated the result by comparing it with my own work so you can use the code to calculate the trend analysis anywhere you want. I wish all of us can optimize our code and share our knowledge cross the national hurdles!

Rightnow I am still a master student, so if you find any errors or improvable  place, please don't hesitate to discuss with me on my researchgate https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Siqing-Zhao or via email: zhaosiqing@mail.bnu.edu.cn

If this code really helps you, please add the citation of my article

Zhao, S.; Zhao, X.; Zhao, J.; Liu, N.; Sun, M.; Mu, B.; Sun, N.; Guo, Y. Grassland Conservation Effectiveness of National Nature Reserves in Northern China. Remote Sens. 2022, 14, 1760. https://doi.org/10.3390/rs14071760

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your differences all have a magnitude less than one, so the int() in the sign function is setting all values to 0.

If you're really just getting the sign of the difference, then you can use something like:

```
function sign(a, b) {
    return a.expression("diff < 0 ? -1 : (diff > 0 ? 1 : 0)", {
        diff: a.subtract(b)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, and I also discover my error in the code. When excluding the .int() then I can get the map with different values. Maybe .int() function is limited in google earth engine because it rounds all the values into 0 value. Then my next step is to reclassify these values using Arcgis software.

Answer (score 0):

These return values obtained by the code indicated by *https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/nonparametric-trends* are strange. I test with the series of a specific pixel with the pymannkendall library in python and the returned values are different, in different measurement units. I removed the int() as well, but I'm not sure that the mann kendall function defined in this code is correct, as even in the variance I get a different value than what I find with pymannkendall.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or a case study?

Comment: It actually has to do with the question, as it's from the same tutorial code that the other user submitted. However, it is a consideration of what I have seen in my case, that I am suspicious of the outcome. I don't know if I would have to open another topic. If yes, I'm sorry.